# making charts interactive in primefaces3

Tags: primefaces

Trying to make my p:barChart interactive and getting jQuery.js.jsf script error in the browser window.

I added the following code as per the primefaces lab showcase to make my chart interactive,

java service code:

```
 public void itemSelect(ItemSelectEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Item selected",   
                        "Item Index: " + event.getItemIndex() + ", Series Index:" + event.getSeriesIndex());   


        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);   
    }
```

I use Primefaces3.M2 release and JSF2.
Can anybody help me fix this.